# Can't make sense of this particular proof (For any two well-orderings, one is isomorphic to an initial segment of the other)

Tags: set-theory

[image: from this book: https://st.openlogicproject.org/]

The proof is from this book: https://st.openlogicproject.org/ page 136

I can accept that $f$ is a function, I even see it is an isomorphism.

However, I fail to see that Lemma 10.10 makes dom($f$) an initial segment of $A$ or ran($f$) an initial segment of $B$.

Leaving this to one's side, I follow the proof up to the last assertion: $\langle a, b \rangle \in f$. So what? It says, 'a contradiction'. Where was the opposite derived?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $a$ is the $<$-minimal member of $A \setminus \text{dom}(f)$ and $b$ the $<$-minimal member of $B \setminus \text{ran}(f)$. So, $(a, b) \not \in f$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you...got it. Can you see why Lemma 10.10 implies the other claim (the other question in my post)?

Comment: Sure. I will show that $dom(f)$ is an initial segment. By assumption, $\exists g \exists b(g: (A_{a_2}, <_{a_2}) \cong (B_b, <_{b}))$. Since $a_1 < a_2$, $a_1 \in A_{a_2}$. So, by Lemma 10.10. we have $g\restriction A_{a_1}: A_{a_1} \cong B_{g(a_1)}$. Consequently, $a_1 \in dom(f)$. The reasoning to show that $ran(f)$ is an initial segment proceeds analogously. For this note that the inverse of an isomorphism is again an isomorphism.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again...now it is complete. Nice to get help so quickly and easily.. :) Hope I can return back to the community something usefull soon..